# JPA Repository with Inheritance - SQL Error: Column 'clazz_' not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have designed the entities in my application to follow the Hibernate's inheritance strategy `Inheritance.JOINED`.

The base abstract class is `Activity` and the concrete derived classes are `Exercise` and `Contest`:
(currently, `Exercise` and `Contest` are almost identical)

**Activity.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "activity")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class Activity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "activity_id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id", nullable = false)
    private Course course;
}
```

**Exercise.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Exercise extends Activity {
    
    @Column(name = "deadline")
    private Date deadline;
    
    @Column(name = "task", nullable = false)
    private String task;
}
```

**Contest.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contest")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Contest extends Activity {
    
    @Column(name = "start")
    private Date start;
    
    @Column(name = "task", nullable = false)
    private String task;
}
```

My Repository looks like this:

**ActivityRepository.java**

```
public interface ActivityRepository extends JpaRepository<Activity, Integer>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM activity a WHERE course_id=:course_id", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Activity> getByCourseId(@Param("course_id") int course_id);
}
```

When executing the Query `getByCourseId()`, I receive the SQL Error `Column 'clazz_' not found`.

Comment: Activity is an abstract class and you are using a native query. How does the engine know how to build an Exercice or a Contest  instance ?

Comment: What is the `Course` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a native query. Try this :

```
public List<Activity> findByCourse(Course course);
```

It should work without writing the query which is :

```
select a from Activity where a.course = :course
```